# How I exports a const outside another const using app.post? Express Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module.exports

I have a file signupResponse.js

```
const foundRegisterUser = function(err, foundUser){
        if(!err){
            console.log("Não tivemos erros")
            if(!foundUser){
                if(req.body.password == req.body.passwordConfirmation){ 
                    User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
                        if (err){/ 
                            console.log(err);
                        } else { 
                            console.log("Success")
                            res.render("welcome")
                        } 
                    })
                } else { 
                    res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_INVALID_PASSWORD, msg1:"", msg2:""})
                }
            } else { 
                res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_INVALID_USER, msg1:"", msg2:"" })
            }
        } else {
            res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_ERROR_REGISTER, msg1:"", msg2:""})
        }   
    }
const signupresponse = (req, res) => {
    Register.findOne({username: req.body.email}, function(err, foundUser){ 
        if(!err){ /
            if(!foundUser){
                console.log("Usuário não encontrado")
                res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_0, msg1:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_1, msg2:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_2 })
                }
            else { 
                User.findOne({username: req.body.email}, 
                    foundRegisterUser(err, foundUser)
                    )
            } 
        } else {
            res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_ERROR_REGISTER, msg1:"", msg2:"" })
        }
    })
}

module.exports = signupresponse
```

I try to export to app.js

```
const signupResponse = require("./funcoes/signupResponse")
app.post("/signup", signupResponse)
```

This return ReferenceError: res is not defined
But when I put everything inside signupResponse and exports again, this works well:

```
const signupresponse = (req, res) => {
    Register.findOne({username: req.body.email}, function(err, foundUser){ 
        if(!err){ 
            if(!foundUser){
                console.log("Usuário não encontrado")
                res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_0, msg1:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_1, msg2:MSG_NOT_FOUND_REGISTER_2 })
                }
            else { 
                User.findOne({username: req.body.email}, function(err, foundUser) {
                    if(!err){
                        console.log("Não tivemos erros")
                        if(!foundUser){
                            if(req.body.password == req.body.passwordConfirmation){ 
                                User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
                                    if (err){/ 
                                        console.log(err);
                                    } else { 
                                        console.log("Success")
                                        res.render("welcome")
                                    } 
                                })
                            } else { 
                                res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_INVALID_PASSWORD, msg1:"", msg2:""})
                            }
                        } else { 
                            res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_INVALID_USER, msg1:"", msg2:"" })
                        }
                    } else {
                        res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_ERROR_REGISTER, msg1:"", msg2:""})
                    } 
                })
            } 
        } else {
            res.render("registerFailure",{msg0:MSG_ERROR_REGISTER, msg1:"", msg2:"" })
        }
    })
}

module.exports = signupresponse
```

The app works good and returns no errors.
I don't know how to use module.exports when has a lot of function to export. 
How I export this signupResponse and put another function inside it without error?
Thanks!

Comment: Try it like this: `module.exports = { signupresponse }`. It is now an object with the key *signupresponse*.

Comment: This return: Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of `export`, but a problem of scope of the ´´res´´ variable.

In the first code example, you have this error because you try to access the `res` object inside `foundRegisterUser` but this function doesn't know the `res` object. You define a `res` object in your other funtion `signupresponse`, ant the res object exist only inside of it. `foundRegisterUser`does not have any knowledge of it.

It works in your second example because you do not have a problem of scope for `res` in this case: everything is inside the same function and then your callback has access to 
 the `res` object.

One way to make your first example work would be to put the definition of `foundRegisterUser` inside `signupresponse` like this:

```
const signupresponse = (req, res) => {
    const foundRegisterUser = function(err, foundUser){ ... };
    Register.findOne({username: req.body.email}, function(err, foundUser){...
```

It would not be the prettiest, and would let plenty of room for structure improvement, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I solve the problem,  I pass req, res inside foundRegisterUser:  

                    const foundRegisterUser = (req, res) => function(err, foundUser) { ...}